# Using GPL or LGPL licensed framework for web application

Tags: gpl, distribution, lgpl, website

I am developing a web application which streams videos. For the frontend I intend to use the richfaces framework for jsf. That framework is licensed under the LGPL v2. Does that mean that I have to make it possible to use different version of this framework by the user as the license indicates?

I actually want to understand whether running an application on a server could be referred as distribution or not?

Answer (score 11):

Running an application on a server is never considered distribution, and you're not bound by the terms of the LGPL for distribution.

Please do note that running javascript in the browser *does* mean distribution. I'm not familiar with the framework, so I don't know if that's relevant here.

The only widely used open source license which puts obligations on you when you run software on a server and let users interact with it is the [AGPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.en.html).

Answer (score 7):

Under the LGPL, running the software under a web server of any sort does not qualify as distribution. As noted in Martijn's answer, passing JavaScript and any markup to create the webpage does qualify as distribution. Here's a small flow chart that might help:

> [image: Distribution flow chart]

If your code running on the server is LGPL, this does not count as distribution. However, if you are sending code over a connection to the client in the web app, this does count as distribution.

If you're running an LGPL, or GPL licensed application *only on the server*, then you're not distributing anything. The exception to this is the AGPL license, where running an application on the server qualifies as distribution.

Comment: AGPL note: using AGPL, as I understand, doesn't automatically mean you are distributing. Only if you are making _the specific functionality_ of the AGPL software available (say, the AGPL software is DB, and you provide a managed DB service). But happy to take correction.